# how to Suppress Field in mongocxx (c++)?

Tags: c++, mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query, mongo-cxx-driver

I want to know what is equivalent of below code in mongocxx driver (c++)?

```
db.RadarPointsExl.find(
   { age: { $gt: 25, $lte: 50 },
{name:1 }
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My colleague found answer you can use below code using :

```
using bsoncxx::builder::stream::document;
    mongocxx::options::find opts;
    document condition, options;
    mongocxx::instance instance{};
    mongocxx::client client{ mongocxx::uri{} };
    mongocxx::database db = client["RadarDB"];
    mongocxx::collection collection = db["RadarPointsExl"];

    condition << "age" << open_document << "$gt" << 25 << "$lte" << 50 << close_document;
    options << "name" << 1;
    opts.projection(options.view());
    mongocxx::cursor cursor = collection.find(condition.view(), opts);


    for (auto doc : cursor) {
        std::cout << doc["name"].get_utf8().value << "\n";

    }
```

I hope it is useful .